# Rewrite a rewritten url beautified by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to rewrite a rewritten url by the CMS in .htaccess.

The url I want to rewrite is:

```
http://whatever/foo/offer/?offer_id=1213/
```

To:

```
http://whatever/foo/offer/1213/
```

Tried a lot of things, but normal rewrite does not work, like:

```
RewriteRule ^offer/(.*)?$ offer/offer_id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^offer/(.*)?$ offer/?offer_id=$1 [QSA]
```

etc.

How may I do this?
Should I edit the plugin or it can be done with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: WRONG!

You've got your rule backwards, and a little wrong. `^` means "start of URL" and `$` means "end of URL". Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)offer/\?offer_id=(.*)/ $1offer/$2
```

It's a bit clunky but should work.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Nothing is happening. I am writting it at the end of the thousands of lines .htaccess file.

Comment: @JordiHuertas Have you added the funny brackets thing at the end that means "do something"?

Comment: @JordiHuertas What you want is what I'd call a "canonical URL" but I can't find anything on how to do that with `.htaccess`...

Comment: Ok, I am trying to Google about that. Ty.